# How to get a passed "id" param through a link from a gsp file to another gsp file in grails

Tags: grails, hyperlink, parameters

Suppose I have a gsp file with a link with is working with the tag "Read more. This links opens another gsp file name "blog" and if you look at the url bar, you can see my current link is "MyWebApp/post/blog/(current i value). So how do I get the (current i value) wich is actually an integer, from the new blog.gsp file?

Comment: Finally what works for me was a combination of all of your answers. In the main view I used this tag to link the user to the second view: <g:link action="blog" controller="Post"  params="[id: "${i}"]">
            Read more
        </g:link>
In the PostController I put this: def blog()
    {
        def entries = Post.findAll()
        def post = Post.get(params.id)
        [post: post, articles: entries]
    }
In the second view I capture the id value with: <g:set var="k" value="${params.id}"/> and print the correspondent post content with: ${articles[k.toInteger()]?.title} Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
class PostController {

   def list() {
     // this action calls the page that has the "Read more" link
     def posts = Post.list()
     [posts: posts]
   }

   def blog() {
     // this action is triggered by the "Read more" link and
     // renders your blog post where you want the current ID
     def post = Post.get(params.id)
     [post: post]
   }
}
```

blog.gsp

```
<html>
....
${post.id}
....
</html>
```

Comment: Not working! Log: 
Around line 151 of grails-app\views\post\blog.gsp
149:<div class="blogContent">
150:<div class="blogTitle">
151:<h2>Latest from the Blog_01  ${post.id} </h2>
152:<span class="category">posted in // food, customer</span>
153:<div class="clearfix"></div>

Around line 195 of PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
192:   if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cacheOperations)) {
193:    log.debug("No cacheable annotation found for {}:{} {}",
194:      new Object[] { request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), getContext() });
195: chain.doFilter(request, response);
196:return;
197:}

Comment: I can't help if I don't know what you're code looks like up to that point.  You'll need to update your question.  If you're code looks anything like mine, it should work.

Comment: As I said above, I have this tag in my main gsp file: "<a href="${createLink(controller: 'Post',action: 'blog', id: "${i}")}">Readm more</a>" So what I need is to include another tag in blog.gsp that can get, or capture the id value of the previus page

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You can probably do the following

```
<g:link action="blog" controller="post" params="['id': '${i}']">
   Read more
</g:link>
```

---

It depends on what *i* is via url mappings, but I guess it would be *${params.i}*

Comment: I will give more details about how I launch the other gsp file, I use this tag in the current gsp: <a href="${createLink(controller: 'Post',action: 'blog', id: "${i}")}">Readm more</a>

Comment: And how do I retrieve the 'id' param in the other gsp file? I mean, what tag shoul I use?

Answer (score 0):

When you create links or submit forms, your information is stored in the `params` Map. This map is accessible by your controller and with that you can do whatever you need like passing the data to your view, or perform query's and then pass the result to the view.

The simplest way of understand the flow controller > view > controller > another view is to use grails command [generate-all](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html) and check the basic crud for your domain class. See how the `show` and `edit` works.

Gregg's answer is probably what you're looking for. If it not works, maybe you're passing an invalid id. You can check if the post exists before showing the content using `<g:if>`, for example:

```
<g:if test="${post}">
  id: ${post.id}
</g:if>
<g:else>
<p>This blog post don't exists.</p>
</g:else>
```

Comment: I think this is not about if the post actually exists or not because I can clearly see that the id is appearing at the end of the URL like: post/blog/(id value). The idea is that I have a single gsp file to show a post and depending on the id value of the URL I change the content dinamycally, if a user clicks on post "1" then the id should be "1" and according to that number the gsp should put the right content, in this case the content of post 1